# Customizing console output - surefire plugin

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

This is my console output after I run `mvn clean test`

```
[WARNING] Tests run: 197, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 5, Time elapsed: 5,446.747 s - in TestSuite
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[WARNING] Tests run: 193, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:30 h
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-03T18:22:40+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to change it to show which tests were skipped [one is actually skipped, rest are just retries from flaky tests]?
Ideally I could configure it to show test, reason in a clear and concise way.
I am using:
TestNG 6.10, SureFire 3m4. I am not even sure if the surefire controls this output or what?
I did a lot of research but nothing seems to pop up about it.

I KNOW there is a report file, and all is clear there, I just want it in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command mvn clean test-Dsurefire.printSummary=false to print the summary of failed test cases but I don't think there is any command to print the skipped test cases in maven.